# Визуальная таблица SQL в Visual Studio в универсальном проекте Windows 10

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, sqlite3

Нужно визуализировать данные таблицы SQLite в виде таблицы. Есть схожие вопросы в данном сервисе, но проблема в следующем: универсальный проект Windows 10 не поддерживает DataGridView. Для меня остающиеся очевидные варианты из этого же направления - GridView и Grid. Grid очевидно не подходит, а с GridView не понятно, сможет ли справится с такой задачей... а если и может, то не понятно, как действовать в этом направлении.

Вопрос, как можно визуализировать данные таблицы sqlite с достаточно большим объемом информации (3тыс. и больше строк)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Надеюсь, что вам знакомы привязки данных (биндинги). В приложениях UWP появились компилируемые привязки данных, которые работают быстрее.
Создаете класс со структурой данных.

```
public class ClassInfo 
{
    private string _name;
    private int _surname;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set { _name = value;}
    }

    public int Surname
    {
        get { return _surname; }
        set { _surname = value;}
    }
}
```

Далее в XAML добавляете GridView или как в следующем примере ListView с шаблоном одного элемента внутри:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind mydata}" Width="200" Height="500">
 <ListView.ItemTemplate>
     <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:ClassInfo">
         <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
             <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Name}" x:Phase="0" ></TextBlock>
             <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Surname}" x:Phase="1" ></TextBlock> 
         </StackPanel>
     </DataTemplate>
 </ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

Вам нужна будет не простая коллекция, а Observable (так как она при изменении заставляет UI XAML изменится тоже):

```
ObservableCollection<ImageInfo> mydata = new ObservableCollection<ImageInfo>();
```

Если вы посмотрите на XAML, то к ней привязаны данные - ItemsSource="{x:Bind mydata}".

Ну и где-нибудь в коде теперь можно задать контекст данных:

```
this.DataContext = mydata;
```

и добавить какие-нибудь данные:

```
mydata.Add(new ClassInfo { Name = "Алексей", Surname = "Соммер" });
```

Если вас интересует как выбрать данные из SQLite в UWP, то сделать это можно используя [SQLite for Universal Windows Platform](http://sqlite.org/download.html)
Скачиваете и устанавливаете vsix. Добавляете ссылку и пространство имен

```
using SQLitePCL;
```

И считываете данные в цикле

```
using (var statement = conn.Prepare("SELECT Name, Surname FROM People WHERE FirstName='Alex'"))
                {
       while (statement.Step() == SQLiteResult.ROW)
        {
mydata.Add(new ClassInfo { Name = (string)statement[0], Surname = (string)statement[1] });
        }
                }
```